# How do I know whether I need to compile Less files for Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: less, twitter-bootstrap-3

**What advantages does compiling the LESS files have** over just git cloning the Bootstrap Repo and copy/pasting various bootstrap.css files from there?

Comment: Using a CSS preprocessor speed up development time as well as giving you addition features. Google it as there is a ton of info out there on the subject. If you are a professional developer, using a CSS preprocessor is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LESS compiled Bootstrap you can get a customized and minified CSS file exclusive for your requirements (classes and colors). It is just performance, it reduce file size and petitions to the web server, principally.

Take a look to Bootstrap online LESS compiler (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to view all the variables you can choose.

Comment: Is it nessecary to compile less Bootstrap for an HTML CSS site only?

Comment: No, just use the .min.js and .min.css versions, they are compiled and minified already (and available through the official CDN).

Comment: When you have finished the development, you can take a look to the online compiler and maybe you can make a smaller js/css versions, at this point you will know almost exactly what components you are using.

Comment: if I want to customize/add my own css, do I do that in their css file or do I make my own custom.css file?

Comment: Yes, so if you want to override bootstrap classes, just add your custom.css file after the bootstrap.css `<link>` ref